# Allow only one number in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

Im new in programming and i want to ask for a help. I'm asking for the code in vb.net where after i put period or "." In the textbox I want the textbox to accept only number 5. The textbox will not accept any letters or numbers or special characters in my textbox after I put period or "."

Comment: Please include code that shows the issue.

Comment: use keydown event,  if last text ="."  then e. handle = not e. char.equal(5)... i cant remember the syntax but thats the way!

Comment: Ow im sorry. Im new in programming and i know only little in vb.net and im asking for the code because i have no idea. Im just gonna edit my question. Sorry

Comment: i am on my bed and ready to sleep,  you can try my method.  Use keydown event in textbox,  check if the last text is "."  or not,  if it ".",  then e. handle = not  e. key. equal(5) ...  the only way to know if something is work or not is try it!

Comment: I tried E.handled = not e.char.equal(5) and  e.handled = not e.key.equal(5) but theres an error in both e.char and e.key it says  'key is not a member of system.windows.forms.KeyEventArgs' and 'char is not a member of system.windows.forms.KeyEventArgs'. Both in keydown event

Answer (score 0):

This might help you:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyDown
    If Trim(CType(sender, TextBox).Text).EndsWith(".") AndAlso (e.KeyData <> Keys.D5) Then
        e.SuppressKeyPress = True
        e.Handled = True  
        Console.WriteLine("Type another key. this is not number 5")
    End If
End Sub
```